# What does $\mathbb{C}[f]$ mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-space

Let $f\colon E \to E$ be an endomorphism of stable bundles over a variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

What does the notation $\mathbb{C}[f]$ mean? (This is supposed to be a field if $f$ is an isomorphism.)

Reference: Le Potier's book on Vector Bundles.

Comment: What page? I have a good guess for what this means, but I want to double check before leaving an answer

Comment: p. 74-75 in Le Potier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 75, the author says

> Consider the commutative algebra $\mathbb{C}[f]$ generated by $f$.

This answers your question, then. We know that $f \in \text{End}(E)$, where $\text{End}(E)$ is an endomorphism ring. So we can look at the smallest subring containing $f$ and closed under scalar multiplication.

Why is $\mathbb{C}[f]$ the notation for this? Well think about what an element of "the ring generated by $f$" should look like! Certainly $f$ should be there. But it's closed under multiplication, so we should also have $f^2$,$f^3$, etc. It's closed under scalar multiplication and addition, so actually we should get all polynomials in $f$. But it's reasonable to refer to "polynomials in $f$" by the notation $\mathbb{C}[f]$.

Now, since we're talking about *coherent sheaves*, we know our modules are finite dimensional. Then if $f$ is an isomorphism, actually $f^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $f$ (basically since $P(f) = 0$ by the [cayley-hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), so if $f$ is invertible we can rearrange this to get $f^{-1} = Q(f)$). Thus when $f$ is invertible, $f^{-1} \in \mathbb{C}[f]$ so that actually $\mathbb{C}[f]$ is a field.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yes and because $f$ is an isomorphism, the constant term of $P(f)$ can’t be zero. Very nice!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, you should mark it as such by clicking the green check mark so that other users know how to spend their time ^_^

Comment: Oh I’m just a random person who’s scrolling through math.SE due to insomnia, not OP lol

Comment: @Arkady -- lmao, I should clearly also go to bed, haha